# How to use delegate methods to pass objects between two view controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using the Utility Application project to Xcode 4.2, then I am adding two text fields for each view: `main view` and the `flipside view`.
Now I wish to assign the value of the `flipside` text field to mainview text field.

**MainViewController.h**

```
      #import "FlipsideViewController.h"

      @interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate>  {
        UITextField *nameField;
      }
      @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;

      - (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender;

      @end
```

**FlipsideViewController.h**

```
      @class FlipsideViewController;

      @protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
         - (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
      @end

      @interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
          UITextField *changeText;
      }
      @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *changeText;
      @property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

      - (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

      @end
```

**FlipsideViewController.m**

```
      #import "FlipsideViewController.h"

      @implementation FlipsideViewController

      @synthesize delegate = _delegate;
      @synthesize changeText;

      - (IBAction)done:(id)sender
      { 
        [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
      }
```

When the done action starts, i want the `changetext` value be assigned to `nameField` text.
How do I do this?

Comment: [Here is a nice answer, how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8575711/593709)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **MainViewController.m**, implement the `flipSideViewControllerDelegate` method as:

```
 - (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
self.nameField.text=controller.changeText.text;
}
```

So when the `done:` method is called, this delegate method is also called with your `flipSideViewController` object as the argument, through which `changeText` can be accessed.

EDIT to answer question in comment:

In your protocol FlipSideViewControllerDelegate, add this method:

```
 - (void)flipsideViewControllerDidSelect:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

Then it is similar to the other delegate method implementation in **MainViewController.m**
, which is how the protocol works really. If your MainViewController conforms to the protocol, it can implement methods of that protocol. By default all the methods declared in the protocol are optional, but you have the option to specify if the method is optional or required by using

```
@optional
//list of methods
@required
//list of methods
```

Bear in mind that if your a method is declared as required in the protocol, any class conforming to that protocol **must** implement it. Anyway, in your **MainViewController.m**:

```
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidSelect:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
int anInt=indexPath.row;
self.nameField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",anInt];
}
```

Comment: Thk very much! If i would implement a table view in the flipsideViewController.m: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { ..... } How pass the value of row in the text field main view?