# Changing a UIImageView's .image from another ViewController class

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, singleton

I have a `ViewController` which has an embedded `UIImageView`. Another `ViewController` has a button which should change the `UIImageView's` `.image` by click.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I've read something about a singleton class but:

- I'm not quite sure if I get the point of a `singleton class` correctly, maybe so. could explain it to me in easy words?
- There is a way using the `AppDelegate` ... but I think that's not the best solution.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Ich want to call the `setUpExternalDisplay`-method (which uses instance variables) in `FirstAssistantViewController`. My Code:

`FirstAssistantViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DetailTableViewController.h"

@interface FirstAssistantViewController : UIViewController <DetailTableViewControllerDelegate>
{
DetailTableViewController * detailTableViewController;
}
```

`DetailTableViewController.h`

```
#import "AssistantRootViewController.h"
#import "FirstAssistantViewController.h"

@protocol DetailTableViewControllerDelegate
- (void) setUpExternalDisplay;
@end

@interface DetailTableViewController : UITableViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, DetailTableViewControllerDelegate>
{
id <DetailTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}
- (void)showModalHelpViewController;
- (void)showModalAssistantViewController;
@end
```

**UPDATE 2:**

It now does the following error messages:

`Cannot find protocol declaration for 'DetailTableViewControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'UIPageViewControllerDelegate'?`

`Property 'DTVCdelegate' requires method 'DTVCdelegate' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation`

If I `@synthesize`:

`Existing ivar 'DTVCdelegate' for unsafe_unretained property 'DTVCdelegate' must be __unsafe_unretained`

Don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try to use NSNotification.

Comment: Do you have a code snippet to do this with more than one view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Could that button in the other view controller be a Bool (on/off) so when it changes (true>false) the image also changes? Just an idea...Ill think about it

Comment: No. I have a bunch of `UIImages` and buttons. Each button sets a new `UIImage`.

Comment: Is this all on a single view?

Comment: I have an external Display and a ViewController which manages it.

Comment: Does that mean yes? (Are the buttons and the UIImages on the same screen?)

Comment: No. Controller a) manages an external Display with an UIImageView and Controller b) manages an UIView on the iPad screen which should call methods on controller a).

Answer (score 0):

First off, get yourself familiarized with how to use protocols and call methods between 2 different view controllers from this answer [How to use delegate methods to pass objects between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623994/how-to-use-delegate-methods-to-pass-objects-between-two-view-controllers/8624090#8624090).

Let object1(ViewController1) have the imageView and object2(ViewController2) have the buttons. All of the buttons are connected to a single method. I assume you have the images in object1. So, what you need is use some kind of way to identify the image in object1, perhaps the button's tag. Now you should have an object `delegate` in object2 which points to object1. You can then call in the button method

```
[self.delegate changeImageTo:button.tag]//I am just using tag in this case, but you can use other ways
```

In your ViewController1, you should implement the `changeImageTo:`

```
-(void) changeImageTo:(NSUInteger)imageID
{
imageView.image=//get it from the image source using imageID
[imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Create a protocol in `ViewContoller2` as `ViewController2Delegate`

```
@protocol ViewController2Delegate
-(void) changeImageTo:(NSUInteger)imageID;
@end
```

and create delegate as an instance variable in `ViewController2` class.

```
id <ViewController2Delegate> delegate;
```

Don't forget to create a property for it too.

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) id <ViewController2Delegate> delegate;
```

and synthesize in the .m file

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

And implement `ViewController2Delegate` protocol in `ViewController1` class.

Comment: @Darwin I ve updated my answer. When you create object 2 just assign its delegate to object1

Comment: I does not work. I think your response is really good but I do not understand how to code this. I did the `@protocol` and the `id <View.....` in `VC2.h`. In `VC1.h` I did `#import "VC2.h`. In `VC2.m` I do not find my `[self.delegate function]`.

Comment: @Darwin Did you implement the changeImageTo: method in VC1.m ? Is your delegate nil or did you not assign object2.delegate=object1 when creating it?

Comment: @Darwin Very much welcome. You had forgotten to create the property. It should work now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6231/discussion-between-madhavanrp-and-darwin)

Comment: It says `Cannot find protocol declaration`? And the second error is something like (at the @synthesize row) `delegate must be __unsafe_unretained`?

Answer (score 0):

take one string in secondviewcontroller and declare the property and synthesize it.Then when you are going from firstviewcontroller to second view then change the string like this  second view.somestring= @"one.png".In view did load of secondviewcontroller use the same string to change the image.